# How can i set the value of a stringobject in side the viewcontroller in my navigation stack?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I Have an application in which i had the array of view controllers
now i want to pop to a particular vie controller .also i need to set the value of a string object inside that viewcontroller to nil.I am doing like this ,but how to set the string value inside that view controller is my bottle neck?can anybody help me?`

```
NSArray *array1 = [self.navigationController viewControllers];
NSLog(@"%@beforelogout",[self.navigationController viewControllers]);
[self.navigationController popToViewController:[array1 objectAtIndex:1] animated:YES];
```

`
i need to set the string inside [array1 objectAtIndex:0].?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your `[array1 objectAtIndex:0]` is simply your navigationcontrollers rootview. You could do like this:

```
RootViewController *rootView = (RootViewController*)[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
rootView.yourProperty = nil;
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Change the "RootViewController" to the self made class of your rootview.

Comment: sorry it is not the rootview,actually it is object at index 1

Comment: Does not matter. The procedure is the same.

Comment: I have added [self.navigationController popToViewController:rootView animated:YES]; works fine .anyway its my mistake that i wrote it as array1 objectAtIndex:0